# Adding connector in Subversive

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I would like to add another connector for testing in Subversive. However, under Preference > Team > SVN > SVN Connector, I can't seem to see how I would do this.

Should I re-install the plugin and select more than one connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed the plugin and made sure to add JavaHL and SVNKit. I am now able to select either one within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, goto help--> Install New Software

in,install window, enter the below url in work with text field
 http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/

then in the below box you'll get list of connector, select those and click next...

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a subversive svn connector, there must be 'http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/' in Available Software Sites.(in case of Kepler) Other connectors or updates can be installed from there.

Comment: I want to add a connector. I only had JavaHL installed and wanted to add SVNKit.